# React IOS Safari - onClick not working - 2020

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, mobile-safari, reactstrap

Alright - I have done a bunch of research but still cant get this button to click on IOS safari.

I am using react 16.13.1 - It is a Reactstrap/Bootstrap Button in a functional component.

You can see the button and the whole component below - it is the search button in the render.

I have tried adding the inline `style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}` to the button... still nothing.

I saw that this was an issue years ago but cant figure out why its happening now.

It started off not working... then started working again.. then it worked for some iphones and not others... now it doesnt work at all again. I have not really touched this button either! So confused - hopefully someone can help.

You can see I have a onChange event as well, attached to the inputs - It triggers the same function. It simply makes it so when the user hits enter, the search fires. This doesnt work as well in mobile safari.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Card, Input, InputGroup, Button } from 'reactstrap'
import Geocode from "react-geocode";
import { genres } from '../../../uitls/QuoteCards/genres'

// set response language. Defaults to english.
Geocode.setLanguage("en");

// set response region. Its optional.
// A Geocoding request with region=es (Spain) will return the Spanish city.
Geocode.setRegion("us");

// set Google Maps Geocoding API for purposes of quota management. Its optional but recommended.
Geocode.setApiKey(process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API);

export default function LocationInput(props) {
    const [ locationText, setLocationText ] = useState(props.savedLocationText)
    const [ location, setLocation ] = useState(props.savedLocation)
    const [ genre, setGenre ] = useState(props.savedGenre)
    const [ searchShowType, setSearchShowType ] = useState(props.showType)

    useEffect(() => {
    props.filterByGenre(genre)
    }, [genre])

    useEffect(() => {
        props.filterByShowType(searchShowType)
    }, [searchShowType])

    const searchByLocation = (e) => {
        if(e.target.value){
            setLocationText(e.target.value[0].toUpperCase() + e.target.value.slice(1))
        }
    }

    const handleSearch = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await Geocode.fromAddress(locationText)
            const { lat, lng } = await response.results[0].geometry.location
            props.searchLocation([lng, lat], locationText)
            setLocation([lng, lat])
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    const handleGenreInput = e => {
    if(e.target.value === ''){
        setGenre('Genre')
    }else {
        setGenre(e.target.value[0].toUpperCase() +  
        e.target.value.slice(1))
    }
    }

    const handleShowTypeInput = e => {
        if(e.target.value === ''){
            setSearchShowType('Show Type')
        }else{
            setSearchShowType(e.target.value)
        }
    }

    const onKeyDown = (e) => {
        if(e.keyCode === 13){
            handleSearch()
        }
    }

    return (
        <Card color="light" className="w-100 d-flex py-3 mb-1 justify-content-between align-items-center align-self-center">
            <InputGroup className='d-flex flex-row align-self-center w-100 mx-4'>
                <Input id="locationInputField" type="text" placeholder={props.savedLocationText ? props.savedLocationText : 'Address - City - State'} className="w-25 mx-1 rounded" onChange={searchByLocation} autoComplete="off" onKeyDown={onKeyDown} style={{
                    display: location ? 'none' : 'flex'
                }} />
                <Input onChange={handleGenreInput} autoComplete='off' placeholder={props.savedGenre} className=" w-25 align-self-center rounded mx-1" type="text" list="genre-list" name="genre-list" style={{
                display: location ? 'flex' : 'none'
                }} />
                    <datalist id="genre-list">
                        {props.availableGenres.map(genre => {return <option key={genre} value={genre}>{genre}</option>})}
                    </datalist>
                <Input onChange={handleShowTypeInput} autoComplete='off' placeholder={props.showType} className=" w-25 align-self-center rounded mx-1" type="text" list="showType-list" name="showType-list" style={{
                display: location ? 'flex' : 'none'
                }} />
                    <datalist id="showType-list">
                        {props.availableShowTypes.map(type => {return <option key={type} value={type}>{type}</option>})}
                    </datalist>
                <Button onClick={handleSearch}  color='dark' className='w-25 text-light align-self-center mx-1 justify-content-center' style="cursor:pointer"
                style={{
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    display: location ? 'none': 'flex',
                }}>Search</Button>  
                <Button size='sm' color='dark' className='mx-1' onClick={() => {
                    window.location.reload()
                }} style={{
                    display: location ? 'flex': 'none'
                }}>x</Button>  
            </InputGroup>

        </Card>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits mybrave - Any idea why shes not workin?

Answer (score 0):

Well. It had nothing to do with the onClick event. It had to do with the geocoding api. The api key didnt have the right ip addresses.